# Unity touch watcher implementation

Tags: c#, android, optimization, mobile, touch

I'm trying to implement my swipeManager class into Unity,
all the logic's done, but I need to make sure the class's called once and that it's update() function is called BEFORE the rest checks if (e.g.) swipeManager.swipe.upToDown is true...

Of course i prepared the manager to be static, in order to avoid calling it multiple times (in fact I cannot rely on the automatic update() )...

I'm a total newbie on Unity, so feel free to correct me, I'm actually trying to learn as I develop, so I miss a bit of theory atm (going to learn it soon).

I have both a start and an update function, feel free to call them in comments to say "and here you go with your code".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) for the Unity event functions order or you chan tale a look at [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ScriptExecution.html) if you want to priorize scripts execution order.

Hope it helps.

Comment: uhmmm that helps (i shouldn't use Update, but onTouch(or something like that) )... the point is i need a way to call it only once...
So correct me if i'm wrong: if in my canvas i use a script which calls FixedUpdate() and in it i call a function, it should execute before every other element of the scene calls update, so that when they update() i can check for the updated variables, am i right?

Comment: For general rule, and as the documentation suggest, Fixed Update should be use for calculations because it is called multiple times per frame instead Update wich is called one time per frame. 
You want to call your Swipe function and then, when it was executed and resolved, call another function using the result of your Swipe, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly!
The first function is just a data collection, the second one actually elaborates them on request.

Comment: Well, then you can use some like this. Implement your touch system and just before your finger leave the screen then evaluate the function. You need catch the [touch phase](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-phase.html) and play with them so you just call your function after your swipe function ends.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you really much!